# Edit a spreadsheet of a workbook that is already open

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to open a closed spreadsheet, edit it, save it, and close it.

What I want to do now, is to have VBA code that accesses a workbook that is already open, inserts data into cells in one of the sheets, and then save it.
The code below gives no error, but does not insert the text into the cell.

```
Sub CheckIfWorkBookIsOpen()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim myXL As Object
    
    FileName1 = "C:\Users\rasch\Documents\Daily to do lists\My current to do list8.xlsx"
    FilePath = IsWBOpen(FileName1)
    If FilePath = True Then
        MsgBox "File is Open"
        Set myXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        myXL.Workbooks(FileName1).Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3) = "Helloooooooo!"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is Closed"
    End If
    Set myXL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `IsWBOpen`? Another function you wrote? Put a breakpoint on that line, run it, and then check your variables while it's paused, and step thru it to see why it does nothing. Also, have you been testing with a lot of code like this? You may have invisible instances of Excel running because of that. Maybe reboot, and then try it again.

Comment: You can also try `myXL.Workbooks(Dir(FileName1)).Worksheets` etc... so that you do not include the path when using `FileName1` as the workbook index.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this adaptation of your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckIfWorkBookIsOpen()    
    
    Dim FileName1 As String
    FileName1 = "C:\Users\rasch\Documents\Daily to do lists\My current to do list8.xlsx"

    Dim myXL As Object
    Set myXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") ' set the running instance of Excel and make it available for further calls
            
        Dim wb As Workbook
        If IsWBOpen(myXL, FileName1, _
                    wb) Then
            MsgBox "File is Open"
            wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3) = "Helloooooooo!"
        Else
            MsgBox "File is Closed"
        End If
        
        Set myXL = Nothing
            
End Sub

Function IsWBOpen(myXL As Object, fullFileName As String, _
                  wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String
        fileName = Split(fullFileName, myXL.PathSeparator)(UBound(Split(fullFileName, myXL.PathSeparator)))
        
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore any possible error originated by the following line
            Set wb = myXL.Workbooks(fileName) ' try setting a workbook object as if a workbook with the given name were alerady open
        On Error GoTo 0 ' reset normal error handling
        
            If Not wb Is Nothing Then ' if workbook actually set
                IsWBOpen = UCase$(wb.FullName) = UCase$(fullFileName) ' the searched workbook is open if its path matches the searched workbook one
            End If
End Function
```

While if you're running all this within an Excel VBA session, then you can omit all that myXL handling

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckIfWorkBookIsOpen()
    
    Dim FileName1 As String
    FileName1 = "C:\Users\rasch\Documents\Daily to do lists\My current to do list8.xlsx"
    FileName1 = "c:\Users\Developers\Downloads\Book1 to be deleted.xlsm"
    
        Dim wb As Workbook
        If IsWBOpen(FileName1, _
                    wb) Then
            MsgBox "File is Open"
            wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3) = "Helloooooooo!"
        Else
            MsgBox "File is Closed"
        End If
            
End Sub

Function IsWBOpen(fullFileName As String, _
                  wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String
        fileName = Split(fullFileName, Application.PathSeparator)(UBound(Split(fullFileName, Application.PathSeparator)))
        
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore any possible error originated by the following line
            Set wb = Workbooks(fileName) ' try setting a workbook object as if a workbook with the given name were alerady open
        On Error GoTo 0 ' reset normal error handling
        
            If Not wb Is Nothing Then ' if workbook actually set
                IsWBOpen = UCase$(wb.FullName) = UCase$(fullFileName) ' the searched workbook is open if its path matches the searched workbook one
            End If
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, IsWBOpen is as follows:

Comment: Function IsWBOpen(FileName As String)
    'declare variables
    Dim FileNo As Long
    Dim ErrorNo As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    FileNo = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #FileNo
    Close FileNo
    ErrorNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case ErrorNo
    Case 0
    IsWBOpen = False
    Case 70
    IsWBOpen = True
    Case Else
    Error ErrorNo
    End Select
    End Function

Comment: re: myXL ... I am currently running it from MS Project, but I appreciate the tip!

Comment: Did my solution work for you?